# Integral involving integration by parts on second term

Tags: integration

Can someone please step out the following integration by parts, I do not understand how to get to the solution.
$$\int\Big(\dfrac{e^x}{x}-\dfrac{e^x}{x^2}\Big)\space dx$$
How do I get to $\dfrac{e^x}{x}$ from this it says it is done by integration by parts on the second term but I am still confused, please help :)

Answer (score 1):

No need for integration by parts.

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$.Then $f'(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$

Observe that now your integral is simply $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx$.

Also observe that $(e^xf(x))'=e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)=e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$ which is your integrand.

Thus $\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx=e^xf(x)+C=\dfrac{e^x}{x}+C$ which would be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \left(\frac{e^x}{x}-\frac{e^{x}}{x^2}\right)dx$$
Do integration by parts on the first one and leave the second one. Take $e^x$ as second function.
$$I=\frac{1}{x} e^x+\int \frac{e^{x}}{x^2}dx-\int \frac{e^{x}}{x^2} dx=\frac{e^x}{x}+C$$

Now take second one first then, taking $e^x$ as first function, then
$$I=\int\frac{e^x}{x} dx+\frac{e^{x}}{x}-\int \frac{e^x}{x} dx= \frac{e^x}{x}+C$$

Comment: But OP says to do integration by parts on the *second* one. That should also work, similarly to what's here.

Comment: I have now added the second part.